# Protractor by repeater Iterating over object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, repeater

My `ng-repeat` looks something like this
`<div ng-repeat="(idx, field) in content">`

And in protractor I want to get the row where the `field.type === 'some value'` which I'm not being able to do. I don't know if there's a direct way to do this but my approach at this time is getting all rows with

`element.all(by.repeater('(idx, field) in content'));`
which gives me 10 elements.

And then was trying to get the types using
`element.all(by.repeater('(idx, field) in content').column('field.type'));`
 which gives me 0 elements.

In [Protractor documentation by repeater](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) there are some examples but none use this separation on the repeater.

What am I doing wrong or what could be a different approach to filter these rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it via [`filter()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) + [`evaluate()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate):

```
element.all(by.repeater('(idx, field) in content')).filter(function (row) {
    return row.evaluate("field.type").then(function (fieldType) {
        return fieldType === "some value";
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That done the trick, didn't knew about `evaluate()` :)